# Name use in computational graph image (TensorBoard)

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, graph, tensorboard

I'm a noob in tensorflow and I start working on "[Getting Started With TensorFlow](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.3/get_started/get_started)" tutorial. 
In this tutorial there is an image of graph. In this image I don't find explanation about range and rank node. I feel that these two nodes are used to find range (0 and N-1) and data rank in sum  :
[image]

Is it right ?

When there is such a node in graph is it good to use doc :

https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/range

https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/rank

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right in that `range` and `Rank` on the picture correspond to [`tf.range`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/range) and [`tf.rank`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/rank) ops in tensorflow. They come not from the squares themselves (you can see the `Square` op below), but from [`tf.reduce_sum`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/reduce_sum):

```
loss = tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(linear_model - y)) # sum of the squares
```

If you look at the source code in [`tensorflow/python/ops/math_ops.py`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/ops/math_ops.py#L1214), you can see them clearly in `_ReductionDims` function, which is used by `tf.reduce_sum` internally.